# IP Configure headache

Tags: windows-7

My IP adress gone after sometime of getting internet connection...My IPadress is 172.16.91.79 and subnet mask is 255.255.255.128 and default gateway is 172.16.91.129 told by the operator...
But evrytime i try to set this, a warning sign come on screen saying "the default gateway is not on the same network segment (subnet) that is defined by the IP adress and subnet mask. Do you want to save this configuration ? "

And with this the internet connection is still off.  I really want a solution what should i do??

Answer (score 0):

With a mask of 255.255.255.128, the usable IP addresses are in the range 192.16.91.1 to 192.168.91.127. As you can see, 192.168.91.129 is outside of that range.

A default gateway is typically the first or last IP address in the subnet so if you have no other way to verify the Ip address of your router, perhaps you could try those as your gateway.

Otherwise, ping everything in your subnet and see what responds.

Comment: The first address in a network is the network address, and the last address in a network is the broadcast address, neither of which are usable for host addresses. You should probably say that the gateway is the first or last **_usable_** address in a network, but it could be any usable address in the network.

Comment: I specifically said what the usable address range was. I presumed, (perhaps foolishly judging by your response) the user would be able to deduce the fact that an address outwith the usable range would in fact be....unusable.